# Update a form in parallel with an installation script?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, parallel-processing

I currently have an installation "framework" that does specific things. What I need now to do is be able to call my form in parallel with my script. Something like this:

```
InstallationForm f = new InstallationForm();
Application.Run(f);
InstallSoftware(f);

private static void InstallSoftware(InstallationForm f) {
    f.WriteToTextbox("Starting installation...");
    Utils.Execute(@"C:\temp\setup.msi", @"-s C:\temp\instructions.xml");

    ...

    f.WriteToTextbox("Installation finished");
```

The current way I can do this is by adding the `Form.Shown` handler in `InstallSoftware`, but that seems really messy. Is there anyway I can do this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will not work, because `Application.Run(f)` returns not until the form was closed.

You may use a simplified Model/View/Controller pattern. Create an `InstallationFormController` class that has several events, e.g. for textual notifications to be written to your textbox. The `InstallationForm` registers on these events in it's `OnLoad()` method and then calls `InstallationFormController.Initialize()`. That method starts your installation (on a worker thread/task). That installation callback method fires several text events.

```
InstallationForm f = new InstallationForm(new InstallationFormController());
Application.Run(f);

internal class InstallationFormController
{
  public event EventHandler<DataEventArgsT<string>> NotificationTextChanged;

  public InstallationFormController()
  {
  }

  public void Initialize()
  {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(DoInstallation);
  }

  private void DoInstallation()
  {
    ...

    OnNotificationTextChanged(new DataEventArgsT<string>("Installation finished"));
  }

  private void OnNotificationTextChanged(DataEventArgsT<string> e)
  {
    if(NotificationTextChanged != null)
      NotificationTextChanged(this, e);
  }
}

public class DataEventArgsT<T> : EventArgs
{
  ...
  public T Data { get; set; }
}

internal class InstallationForm : Form
{
  private readonly InstallationFormController _controller;

  public InstallationForm()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  public InstallationForm(InstallationFormController controller) : this()
  {
    if(controller == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("controller")

    _controller = controller;
  }

  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnLoad(e);

    _controller.NotificationTextChanged += Controller_NotificationTextChanged;
    _controller.Initialize();
  }

  protected virtual void Controller_NotificationTextChanged(object sender, DataEventArgsT<string> e)
  {
    if(this.InvokeRequired)
    { // call this method on UI thread!!!
      var callback = new EventHandler<DataEventArgsT<string>>(Controller_NotificationTextChanged);
      this.Invoke(callback, new object[] {sender, e});
    }
    else
    {
      _myTextBox.Text = e.Data;
    }
  }
  ...
}
```